# Imported Type Library no longer working

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-2010, typelib, c++builder-xe2

I have a large project in C++ Builder that seems to have used the function *Import Type Library*. In it is a file with a header like this

```
// ************************************************************************ //
// WARNING                                                                    
// -------                                                                    
// The types declared in this file were generated from data read from a       
// Type Library. If this type library is explicitly or indirectly (via        
// another type library referring to this type library) re-imported, or the   
// 'Refresh' command of the Type Library Editor activated while editing the   
// Type Library, the contents of this file will be regenerated and all        
// manual modifications will be lost.                                         
// ************************************************************************ //

// C++ TLBWRTR : $Revision:   1.134.1.41  $
// File generated on 2003-10-27 12:57:05 from Type Library described below.

// ************************************************************************ //
// Type Lib: C:\WINNT\system32\MQOA.DLL (1)
// IID\LCID: {D7D6E071-DCCD-11D0-AA4B-0060970DEBAE}\0
// Helpfile: 
// DepndLst: 
//   (1) v2.0 stdole, (C:\WINNT\System32\stdole2.tlb)
//   (2) v4.0 StdVCL, (C:\WINNT\System32\STDVCL40.DLL)
// ************************************************************************ //
#ifndef   __MSMQ_OCX_h__
#define   __MSMQ_OCX_h__

#pragma option push -b -w-inl

#include <utilcls.h>
#if !defined(__UTILCLS_H_VERSION) || (__UTILCLS_H_VERSION < 0x0500)
//
// The code generated by the TLIBIMP utility or the Import|TypeLibrary 
// and Import|ActiveX feature of C++Builder rely on specific versions of
// the header file UTILCLS.H found in the INCLUDE\VCL directory. If an 
// older version of the file is detected, you probably need an update/patch.
//
#error "This file requires a newer version of the header UTILCLS.H" \
       "You need to apply an update/patch to your copy of C++Builder"
#endif
#include <olectl.h>
#include <ocidl.h>
#if !defined(_NO_VCL)
#include <stdvcl.hpp>
#endif  //   _NO_VCL
#include <ocxproxy.h>

...
```

As you can see this file was genereated quite long time ago :). I have been able to build this project using **C++ Builder 2010** on **Windows 7 64-bit**. But when I install **XE2** and try to fix all the small issues that arise since it now defaults to **STRICT** instead of **NO_STRICT**, I run into a totaly different issue. The above file, ad others generated in the same way, they no longer work as intended.

I get errors like

> [BCC32 Error] MSMQ_OCX.h(66): E2090 Qualifier 'Oleserver' is not a
>   class or namespace name

Looking for the **MQOA.DLL** it claims to have used nothing of the sort seems to exist. Does anyone have any pointers on how to get around these kind of problems when updating the project to XE2? The project has survived upgrades before and was lastley upgraded to C++ Builder 2010. But I'm more of a Visual Studio person so a lot of the Embarcadero stuff is new territory.

Comment: have you tried re-importing the TypeLibrary into XE2 instead of re-using your older .h file?

Comment: How do I do this? I thought I were to look up the file used, like  **C:\WINNT\system32\MQOA.DLL** in this case. But this file doesn't exist in Windows 7.

Comment: If you don't have the file installed, how do you expect your app to use the TypeLibrary/Object at runtime even if your project compiled OK?

Comment: That's kinda the strange thing. Since in C++ Builder 2010 the exact same code compiles and works and the dll is still not present. My standpoint is that Embarcadero is a bunch of Voodoo magic :)

Comment: You don't need the DLL for compiling. But you do need it at runtime if you are actually using the COM object(s) that are defined in the TypeLibrary.

Comment: Still doesn't explain how it can compile on C++ Builder 2010 but not XE2 on the same machine :)... Well, I'll dig deeper I guess.

Comment: Have you tried simply turning `STRICT` off?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same problem when upgrading from C++ Builder 2010 to XE2. My project says: [BCC32 Error] atlmod.h(487): E2090 Qualifier 'Utilcls' is not a class or namespace name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up **re-importing** the type libraries needed and deleting the old ones, as suggested by Remy Lebeau. It was Microsoft's libraries for **Message Queues** and **XML** in my case.

Note that some other issues giving similar error messages CAN be that the compiler is just confused :). Try compiling without **NO_STRICT** defined.

Comment: If c++ code (generated by the import wizard) still doesn't work you have one more option - importing type library into a Delphi package. Then build & install package with selected project option: "Generate all C++ Builder files".
It seems that the older versions of C++ builder have issues on generating valid C++ wrapper classes using Import wizard. Pascal code generation is much better - it can be compiled without any modifications.
Tested on two type libraries, at least.